# Can gedit open links in a Web browser by clicking on it?

Tags: gedit

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to quickly open links in a text file with a Web browser. Is there a trick or a plugin out there?

Comment: There probabliy isn't, but it's pretty easy to write your own plugin if you know python. You could for example start from the `select word` function of `line_tools.py` in [this toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-improving-plugins/). Just edit `if not re.match("\w", char)` so it selects a url and get your browser to open it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the External Tools Plugin that ships with Gedit. Select `Tools` > `Manage External Tools`. Create a new tool by clicking the little `+` icon in the lower-left and name it "Open Link" (or whatever you want). Use the following code within the `Edit` box (assuming you're using Firefox):

```
#!/bin/sh
xargs -I '{}' firefox '{}'
```

Then specify your shortcut key and make sure the `Input` is set to `Current word`. You can now open a link if the cursor is anywhere in the word (the URL) by choosing `Tools` > `External Tools` > `Open Link` or using your keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

I use Jean-Philippe's [Open URI Context Menu](https://github.com/jpfleury/open-uri-context-menu) plugin. It doesnt have a shortcut key but uses a simple right-click to open the link.

Just upgraded to Gedit 2.8 and version 2 of this plugin is way faster now.

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of gedit have the appropriate plugin **built-in**. Simply go to ☰ → Preferences → Plugins and enable "Open Links".

You can then right-click any link and a new context menu entry "Open Link" will be at the very top.

[image: screenshot highlighting the described plugin in the list]